# не работает апатч вебмин

Tags: ubuntu, apache, веб-сервер

создаю виртуальный хост->выглядит все нормально, при переходе на него выдает:
Не удается получить доступ к сайту

буду очень признателен, если вы мне хоть как-то поможете

скрины:

[image: вебмин]

[image: ури]

UPDATE

при указании вместо домена айди он пишет: превышено время ожинания
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по тому, что такой домен не зарегистрирован - вы просто его не купили. От того, что вы поковыряли какие-то настройки, домен не появится в системе доменных имён, его нужно покупать у какого-нибудь регистратора

Comment: хорошо, как я понимаю, могу ли я вместо домена юзать айпи сервера? и как это сделать

Comment: Просто указать этот самый айпи вместо домена, возможно?

Comment: указывал, и сейчас указал, просто бесконечная загрузка в мозиле. update превышено время ожидания